# Remote execution of SSH command hangs in ruby using Net::SSH for a particular command

Tags: ruby, cockroachdb, net-ssh

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819418/remote-ssh-command-execution-hangs-in-ruby-using-netssh-for-a-particular-comma), but the answer in such a question didn't work for me.

I am trying to connect the remote ssh server via ruby using Net::SSH.

It is working fine for me for all the commands provided via script and I could read the output of the command successfully.

But when I use the below command it is getting stuck in SSH.exec!(cmd) and control is not returned from the line. Only if i click Ctrl+c in command line the script is getting ended.

```bash
sudo -S su root -c 'cockroach start --advertise-addr=34.207.235.139:26257 --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --store=node0015 --listen-addr=172.31.17.244:26257 --http-addr=172.31.17.244:8080 --join=34.207.235.139:26257 --background --max-sql-memory=.25 --cache=.25;'
```

This is the script I run from a SSH terminal with no issue:

```bash
sudo -S su root -c 'pkill cockroach'
sudo -S su root -c '
cd ~;
mv /home/ubuntu/certs /home/ubuntu/certs.back.back;
mkdir /home/ubuntu/certs;
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory;
cockroach cert create-ca --allow-ca-key-reuse --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key=/home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
cockroach cert create-node localhost 34.207.235.139 172.31.17.244 $(hostname) --certs-dir /home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key /home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
cockroach cert create-client root --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key=/home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
        '
sudo -S su root -c 'cockroach start --advertise-addr=34.207.235.139:26257 --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --store=node0015 --listen-addr=172.31.17.244:26257 --http-addr=172.31.17.244:8080 --join=34.207.235.139:26257 --background --max-sql-memory=.25 --cache=.25;'
```

This is the Ruby script who attempts to do exactly the same, but it gets stuck:

```rb
require 'net/ssh'

ssh = Net::SSH.start('34.207.235.139', 'ubuntu', :keys => './plank.pem', :port => 22)

s = "sudo -S su root -c 'pkill cockroach'"
print "#{s}... "
puts ssh.exec!(s)

s = "sudo -S su root -c '
cd ~;
mv /home/ubuntu/certs /home/ubuntu/certs.back.#{rand(1000000)}};
mkdir /home/ubuntu/certs;
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory;
cockroach cert create-ca --allow-ca-key-reuse --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key=/home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
cockroach cert create-node localhost 34.207.235.139 172.31.17.244 $(hostname) --certs-dir /home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key /home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
cockroach cert create-client root --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --ca-key=/home/ubuntu/my-safe-directory/ca.key;
        '"
print "Installing SSL certifications... "
puts "done (#{ssh.exec!(s)})"

s = "sudo -S su root -c 'cockroach start --advertise-addr=34.207.235.139:26257 --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --store=node0015 --listen-addr=172.31.17.244:26257 --http-addr=172.31.17.244:8080 --join=34.207.235.139:26257 --background --max-sql-memory=.25 --cache=.25;'"
print "Running start command... "
puts "done (#{ssh.exec!(s)})"

# Use this command to verify the node is running:
# ps ax | grep cockroach | grep -v grep
s = "ps ax | grep cockroach | grep -v grep"
print "#{s}... "
sleep(10)
puts "done (#{ssh.exec!(s)})"

ssh.close

exit(0)
```

Here is the put put of the ruby script:

```
C:\code2\blackstack-deployer\examples>ruby start-crdb-environment.rb
sudo -S su root -c 'pkill cockroach'...
Installing SSL certifications... done ()
Running start command...
```

As you can see, the command gets stuck in the line `Running start command...`

I tried putting the command in the background:

```rb
s = "sudo -S su root -c 'cockroach start --advertise-addr=34.207.235.139:26257 --certs-dir=/home/ubuntu/certs --store=node0015 --listen-addr=172.31.17.244:26257 --http-addr=172.31.17.244:8080 --join=34.207.235.139:26257 --background --max-sql-memory=.25 --cache=.25 &'"
print "Running start command... "
puts "done (#{ssh.exec!(s)})"
```

but what happned is that the **cockroach** process never starts (the `ps ax | grep cockroach | grep -v grep` returns nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it.

I added `> /dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the command, and it worked.

```
cockroach start --background --max-sql-memory=.25 --cache=.25 --advertise-addr=%net_remote_ip%:%crdb_database_port% --certs-dir=%crdb_database_certs_path%/certs --store=%name% --listen-addr=%eth0_ip%:%crdb_database_port% --http-addr=%eth0_ip%:%crdb_dashboard_port% --join=%net_remote_ip%:%crdb_database_port% > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any logs/output in the `cockroach-data/logs` directory (should be located where you are running the `start` command from).

Or perhaps try redirecting stdout+stderr to a file and seeing if there is any output there.

My hypothesis is that the CRDB process isn't starting correctly and so control isn't being returned to the terminal. The [cockroachdb docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-start.html) say that the `--background` flag only returns control when the crdb process is ready to accept connections. And the question/answer you linked noted that "SSH.exec! will block further execution until the command returns".

Comment: just saw you found a solution, awesome :)